# Typescript: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, inferred-type

I am trying to create a simple typescript program,

which constraints an object to match a given interface data type.

For example, I have an interface `Config` and a schema object

I want `abc.value` to be restricted as string while `xyz.value` to be restricted as `number`:

```
interface Config {
  abc: string
  xyz: number
}

const schema: XXX = {
  abc: {
    value: '',
  },
  xyz: {
    value: 0,
  },
}
```

I tried using `infer` keyword but cannot get it work properly.

```
const schema: Record<T extends keyof Config ? infer keyof Config : any, any> = {
  abc: {
    value: '',
  },
  xyz: {
    value: 0,
  },
}
```

what I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```js
interface Config {
    abc: string
    xyz: number
}

type Mapped<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: {
        value: T[Prop]
    }
}

const schema: Mapped<Config> = {
    abc: {
        value: '2',
    },
    xyz: {
        value: 0,
    },
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKpaow)

Comment: Thank you! so it looks only `type` keyword is working while `Record` will discard the relationship. Hmm interesting thought they were the same!